# Heroku Node.js webapp deployment fails

Tags: node.js, heroku

> I try to deploy a web app in heruko run in the local machine but when I deploy this app This produces the error

```
2017-01-27T13:42:43.125439+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
2017-01-27T13:42:43.125439+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
2017-01-27T13:42:43.125440+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
2017-01-27T13:42:43.125440+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
2017-01-27T13:42:43.125441+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
2017-01-27T13:42:43.125441+00:00 app[web.1]:     at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
2017-01-27T13:42:43.125441+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
2017-01-27T13:42:43.125442+00:00 app[web.1]:     at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
2017-01-27T13:42:43.216637+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-01-27T13:44:09.044136+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=chokey2.herokuapp.com request_id=b7445c6c-7a17-4b31-b499-4e1a0e60d6b2 fwd="122.164.248.106" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-01-27T13:44:10.071959+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=chokey2.herokuapp.com request_id=0b25572e-f99e-4b26-b534-222599cf80a1 fwd="122.164.248.106" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

> Procfile

```
web: node server.js
```

I have no idea Why this happeninng.

Comment: Did you install packages ? `npm install`

Comment: Can you paste the full error log? Your traceback is cut off making it impossible to see what the problem is.